# How unlocking via Watch uses the laptop password?

Tags: icloud, security, password, apple-watch, unlock

During watch mac unlocking setup, iPhone prompts for laptop user password, but [iOS security guide](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf) (last updated at May 2016) does not describes, how that password will be used.

- Does iPhone needs it only for initial iPhone-Mac-Watch tethering, or maybe it saves password and uses it for every unlock?
- Does it send password (encrypted or not) to iCloud services?
- Do I have to provide new password to iPhone and Watch after I'll change it on Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Apple has now transitioned much of the “enter your iCloud password” to be “enter the password for device X” for unlocking the keys in the keychain.

---

*The rest of this answer is likely out of date, but was the best I knew in 2016.*

I've tested most of your scenarios and don't believe the password ever leaves the Mac. Instead, Apple builds up a cryptographic key pair to sign packet exchange between the watch and the computer with anti-replay aspects and time of flight calculations to ensure the watch is really sending the packets now in real time before the unlock happens.

The anti-replay means that you can't record those packets and then play them later to unlock the Mac. Basically Apple leverages the iCloud security that is set up for two-factor authentication and keychain syncing to exchange the cryptographic keys needed to sign the data to establish a verified signal and prevent hacking into your Mac with a synthetic or bogus signal.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206995

The iOS 10 security guide is not out yet nor is the watchOS 3 guide. I'll update this post if I can find more technical details going forward.